# MATERIALIZED VIEW VS query with ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have the following table `users((username), last_seen)` where last_seen is basically the writetime . Number of records in the table is aprox 10 million. 
Insert is pretty much straightforward `insert into users (username, last_seen) VALUES ([username], now)`

BUT I need to query by the `last_seen` column (this query runs every minute) e.g :

```
select username from users where last_seen < (now - 1 day)
```

I have two options as I see it:

1. use materialized view :

   ```
   CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW users_last_seen AS
   SELECT last_seen, username
   FROM users
   WHERE last_seen IS NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (last_seen, username);
   ```

   and simply query

   ```
   select username from users_last_seen where last_seen < (now - 1 day)
   ```
2. query the users table

   ```
   select username from users where last_seen < (now - 1 day) ALLOW FILTERING
   ```

which one is more efficient? AFAIK materialized view is unstable and have impact on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using [SASI Index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) is the best option in this situation

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK materialized view is unstable

At this point of time, I think so too. But that's not a reason to use ALLOW FILTERING. If not more, it is equally bad.

I would suggest to create another table or change the current structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_status (
    day date,
    id timeuuid,
    user text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((day), id)
);
```

This table is partitioned by each day. You will need to only query over that day's data and prepare the your data on client side program.

`select * from user_status where day = '2015-05-03'`

This is both not heavy on server and client side. Depending on the expected size of data, the partition key can be further tuned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. However this not really solves it because the `day` is a parameter it can be also hours, or any other period . Hence using the suggested table is not a proper solution.

Comment: You could always make multiple queries depending on parameter. 
eg: If it were 3 days, make 3 queries to get the result.

In this way you are identifying the partition for Cassandra and avoiding unpredictable performance issues from full search.

Comment: what I mean is that I need to query with something like this : 
`select username from users where last_seen < (now - 1 hour)`
but also 
`select username from users where last_seen < (now - 1 day)`
so predefine the `day/hour` is no possible. I can divide by the minute but it will create to many partitions isn't it ?